# Binding Multiple dragenter/ dragleave Events in HTML5 Drag 'n Drop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop, frontend

Here's a basic example of what I have going on here:
http://jsfiddle.net/kgqkM/2/

What I'm trying to do is dedicate the area outside of this list to be a "delete" area where I can set up the appropriate logic to remove the dragged element from the page.  I'm attempting to show when the user drags the element off the list it would color the outside red/ semi-transparent.  When I set events on the outer-wrapper, they seem to take over all the dragenter/ dragleave events.

Guessing my issue has to do something with setting the event on the parent div?  I'm starting to try and perhaps have one master event on top and deciding what to do based on the e.target and .parents('.switch'), but insofar it's resulting in buggy behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem that I had to do some (correct) logic on the event target.  I have to refactor my code a bit, but it's working out.

Comment: Well I would mark this as answered but I have to wait two days, apparently.